# how do I hide an element depending on the variable?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, hide

```js
num=1
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num
//button to increase/decrease num
function next() {
num++
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num
}
function before() {
num--
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num
}

//hide and show asdf
if (num=1){
document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "hidden";
} else {
document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div id="Num"></div>
<button onclick="before()">before</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<div id="asdf">asdf</div>
```

I want them to check num and hide or show asdf. I think that num variable is increasing/decreasing as I expected, but asdf isn't showing. I never used if statement out of function so maybe the problem is in there?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator; `==` or `===` are for comparison.

Comment: In JS you use === for equality for example, num === 1. = Is used to assign a value. num= 1 would assign the value to num. Assuming num wasn't a constant

Comment: And you are right, you `if` block runs just once in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.  You're using the former, not the latter.  That's an easily corrected typo.  However, even with that the logic isn't running when you click the button.

The difference is that the increase/decrease functionality is in the functions you're calling, whereas the show/hide functionality is not.  That functionality only runs once when the page loads and then never again.

You can wrap that functionality in a function and invoke it where you want.  For example:

```js
num = 1;
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num;
toggleVisible();

//button to increase/decrease num
function next() {
  num++;
  document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num;
  toggleVisible();
}

function before() {
  num--;
  document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num;
  toggleVisible();
}

//hide and show asdf
function toggleVisible() {
  if (num == 1) {
    document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Num"></div>
<button onclick="before()">before</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<div id="asdf">asdf</div>
```

As an aside, I've added semi-colons to the lines of code.  You'll definitely want to get in the habit of doing that.  Automatic semi-colon insertion exists in JavaScript, but it's not something you should rely on all the time.

Comment: are semi-colons for readability?

Comment: @mahogare: A semicolon terminates a statement, in JavaScript and pretty much all languages descended from C-like syntax.  JavaScript is pretty unique in that it’s forgiving about missing semicolons and tries to infer what was intended.  Sometimes what it infers is not what the programmer expected, and that’s a bug.  An easy way to avoid that entire source of bugs completely is to use semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a setState function for setting the visible num value and for showing/hiding asdf

```js
num=1
document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num
//button to increase/decrease num
function next() {
  num++
  setState();
}

function before() {
  num--
  setState();
}

function setState() {
//hide and show asdf
  document.getElementById("Num").innerHTML = num;
  if (num==1){
document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "hidden";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("asdf").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Num"></div>
<button onclick="before()">before</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<div id="asdf">asdf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const
  elm_Num  = document.querySelector('#Num')
, elm_asdf = document.querySelector('#asdf')
  ;
let num = 1;
testVisu();

function next()
  {
  testVisu(++num);
  }
function before()
  {
  testVisu(--num);
  }
function testVisu() 
  {
  elm_Num.textContent = num;
  elm_asdf.classList.toggle('visu', num === 1);  
  }
```

```css
#asdf      { visibility: hidden; }
#asdf.visu { visibility: visible; }
```

```html
<div id="Num"></div>
<button onclick="before()">before</button>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
<div id="asdf">asdf</div>
```